# scala3 how to make generic zipWith extension method

Tags: scala, scala-3

I was trying to make a simple extension method `zipWith` that just maps a collection `C[A]` to `C[(A, B)]` like this:

```
List(1,2,3) zipWith (_ * 2)
// List((1,2), (2,4), (3,6))
```

I tried with this:

```
scala> extension[A, C[_] <: Iterable[_]] (s: C[A]) def zipWith[B](f: A => B): C[(A, B)] = s map ((x) => (x, f(x)))
-- Error:
1 |extension[A, C[_] <: Iterable[_]] (s: C[A]) def zipWith[B](f: A => B): C[(A, B)] = s map ((x) => (x, f(x)))
  |                                                                                                       ^
  |                                                       Found:    (x : Any)
  |                                                       Required: A
```

What am I missing with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`IterableOnceOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableOnceOps.html) as explained [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collection-operations.html#transforming-any-collection).

```scala
import scala.collection.IterableOnceOps

extension [A, CC[_]](it: IterableOnceOps[A, CC, Any])
  def zipWith[B](f: A => B): CC[(A, B)] =
    it.map(a => (a, f(a)))
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/dN6Gb0LFQiicHwXRwdCm1w/6)*.